# Triplicar informação

Tags: php, upload

fiz este código e deve mover três imagens para a pasta especificada.
Ele nomeia as três imagens, mas está movendo só a primeira.

Já fiz algumas modificações no código, mas infelizmente não dá certo.

Poderiam me dar uma luz de como mover as três imagens para a pasta de destino?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="../APIChamados/recebeUpload.php">
Selecione uma imagem: <input name="arquivo1" type="file">
<br>
Selecione uma imagem: <input name="arquivo2" type="file">
<br>
Selecione uma imagem: <input name="arquivo3" type="file">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Salvar">
</form>


<?php

    // verifica se foi enviado um arquivo
    if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ]  ) && $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
        echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
        echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo2' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
        echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo3' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
        echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
        echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo2' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
        echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo3' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
        echo 'Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'tmp_name' ] . '</strong><br />';
        echo 'Seu tamanho é: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'size' ] . '</strong> Bytes<br /><br />';

        $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
        $nome = $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ];

        // Pega a extensão
        $extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
        $extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );

        // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
        // Aqui eu enfileiro as extensões permitidas e separo por ';'
        // Isso serve apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
        if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {
            // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
            // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
            // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
            $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . '.' . $extensao;

            // Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/img/'.$novoNome;

            // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
            if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
                echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $destino . '</strong><br />';
                echo ' < img src = "' . $destino . '" />';
            }
            else
                echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />';
        }
        else
            echo 'Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"<br />';
    }
    else
        echo 'Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!';

?>
```

Comment: Você executa `move_uploaded_file ($arquivo_tmp, $destino)`, sendo que `$arquivo_tmp`  é definido como `$_FILES['arquivo1']['tmp_name']`, então é esperado que só mova a primeira. Para mover as três, você precisa chamar a função para cada uma delas.

Comment: Vou tentar aqui

Comment: Deveria ficar assim?

// tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
         if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
             
    $i=0;
    foreach($_FILES['arquivo'] as $img){
     switch($_FILES['type'] [$i]){
      echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $destino . '</strong><br />';
      echo ' < img src = "' . $destino . '" />';
     }
    }
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você só executa o move_upload_file para o 'arquivo1'. Altere o trecho em que move o arquivo para o destino para uma function e itere seu $_FILES passando para sua nova function

Ficaria o seguinte:

```
<?php
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo
if ( isset( $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ]  ) && $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'error' ] == 0 ) {
    echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo2' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo3' ][ 'name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
    echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo2' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
    echo 'Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong > ' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo3' ][ 'type' ] . ' </strong ><br />';
    echo 'Temporáriamente foi salvo em: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'tmp_name' ] . '</strong><br />';
    echo 'Seu tamanho é: <strong>' . $_FILES[ 'arquivo1' ][ 'size' ] . '</strong> Bytes<br /><br />';

    foreach ($_FILES as $file) {
        move_file($file);
    }
}
else{
    echo 'Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!';
}


function move_file($file)
{
    $arquivo_tmp = $file[ 'tmp_name' ];
    $nome = $file[ 'name' ];

    // Pega a extensão
    $extensao = pathinfo ( $nome, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

    // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
    $extensao = strtolower ( $extensao );

    // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
    // Aqui eu enfileiro as extensões permitidas e separo por ';'
    // Isso serve apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
    if ( strstr ( '.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao ) ) {
        // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
        // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
        // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
        $novoNome = uniqid ( time () ) . '.' . $extensao;

        // Concatena a pasta com o nome
        $destino = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/img/'.$novoNome;

        // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
        if ( @move_uploaded_file ( $arquivo_tmp, $destino ) ) {
            echo 'Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>' . $destino . '</strong><br />';
            echo ' < img src = "' . $destino . '" />';
        }
        else{
            echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Está dando esse erro

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 17

Comment: Faltou fechar a chave "}" do primeiro IF, alterei o código, verifique agora.

Comment: Está dando como variável indefinida:

Você enviou o arquivo: logoDanfeDM.jpg
Você enviou o arquivo: logoDanfeFrut.jpg
Você enviou o arquivo: logoDanfeItaly.jpg
Este arquivo é do tipo: image/jpeg 
Este arquivo é do tipo: image/jpeg 
Este arquivo é do tipo: image/jpeg 
Temporáriamente foi salvo em: C:\xampp\tmp\php5D66.tmp
Seu tamanho é: 28257 Bytes


Notice: Undefined variable: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 13

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 13

Comment: Estranho que os outros eu não declarei nada (de algum outro jeito do que está), e estão rodando normal.

Comment: Editado novamente, problema estava no foreach.

Comment: Aumentou:

Notice: Undefined index: arquivo1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined index: arquivo1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 25

Warning: strstr(): Empty needle in C:\xampp\htdocs\webchamados\APIChamados\recebeUpload.php on line 36

Modifiquei 'arquivo1' para 'arquivo' e nada...não faço ideia.

Comment: Fiz mais uma alteração, testei por aqui e a principio deu certo.

Comment: Show cara, ficou lindo!!!
Valeu mesmo pela ajuda!!!